# Android + new activity + not displaying the email

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two activities, one where I get the email address, create an Intent and second where I want to display email by receiving the Intent. However I am confused at the displaying part. Do I have to do something in my .xml ??

Here is  my code for second activity

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question. Are you sending an intent and you do not receive it with the bundle? Would you show us some code and explain what exactly are you expecting to happen.

Comment: * Please post your code or some users will close this question!

Comment: I just posted my code where I am getting my Intent. SHOULD I be doing something in my .xml file. ....for it to appear

Answer (score 0):

define intent in that manner :
first activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Email_content",your data);
start Activity(intent);
```

and receive this intent in second class
String value = getIntents().getExtra("Email_content");